# How to call the list state items to the component using redux toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm studying redux toolkit and I want to list the items on the table, however my problem is when I call the state on the redux using useSelector it gives infinite loop. I don't understand where this loop from and why this happen.

CreateAsyncThunk:

```
    export const fetchRemarks = createAsyncThunk(
    'remarks/list_remarks',
    async (_, {dispatch, getState}) => {
        const AuthToken = getState().user.user.token;
        let remark_api_url = process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_SECRET_BASEURL+"check_remark"
        axios.get(remark_api_url, { headers: { 'Authorization': AuthToken, 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } })
        .then(response => {    
            dispatch(list_remarks(response.data))
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('error ' + error);
        });
    }
)
```

Slice:

```
    export const RemarksSlice = createSlice({
    name:"check_in_remarks",
    initialState: {
        list_remarks:[],
        add_check_in_remarks: null,
        create_check_in_success_status: null,
        create_check_in_error_status: null
    },
    reducers: {
        list_remarks: (state, action) => {
            state.list_remarks = action.payload
        },
        create_check_in_success_status: (state, action) => {
            state.create_check_in_success_status = action.payload
        },
        create_check_in_error_status: (state, action) => {
            state.create_check_in_error_status = action.payload
        }
    }
})

export const { add_check_in_remarks, list_remarks, create_check_in_success_status, create_check_in_error_status } = RemarksSlice.actions;

export const AddRemarks = (state) => state.add_check_in_remarks.add_check_in_remarks;
export const ListRemarks = (state) => state.check_in_remarks.list_remarks.data;
export const SuccessCreate = (state) => state.check_in_remarks.create_check_in_success_status;

export default RemarksSlice.reducer;
```

Component:

```
import {add_check_in_remarks, fetchRemarks, CreateRemarks, SuccessCreate, ListRemarks} from '../features/checkInRemarksSlice';

let SuccessStatus = useSelector(SuccessCreate);
let Items = useSelector(ListRemarks);

console.log(Items);

const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchRemarks())
})
```

Infinite Loop Happens:

[image: Loop Error]

DataSource:

```
const dataSource = [
    {
        id: '1',
        check_in_remarks: 'ci',
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        check_in_remarks: 'Customs Brokerage Collections',
    },
    {
        id: '3',
        check_in_remarks: 'Gel Collections',
    },
    {
        id: '4',
        check_in_remarks: 'SI Collections',
    },
    {
        id: '5',
        check_in_remarks: 'Spa Shares',
    },
];
```

As you can see I have manually created my data source, but today I want to use my api.

My Api Look like this:

[image: my API]

Here is my table look like:

```
   <Table
dataSource={dataSource}
columns={columns}
size="small"
rowSelection={{
    type: "checkbox",
    ...rowSelection,
    }}
pagination={false}
footer={() => `Total No. of Checks: ${dataSource.length}`}
/>
```

Here is my listSelector:

```
let ListItem = useSelector(ListRemarks);
console.log(ListItem);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `[]` as the dependency to your useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchRemarks())
}, [])
```

useEffect(() => {}) --> this will run on every re-render. It was running in infinite loop for you because you triggered a fetch request updated the store . Once there is a change in the store your component subscribing to the store will re-render . Now your component re-rendered and again useEffect got fired and this cycle continues.

useEffect(() => {}, []) --> adding this empty array as dependency tells react that run this useEffect only once after the component is rendered.

Comment: great answer, but how to map the data on the table? do I need to use useSelector and map it ?

Comment: What is the shape of your `Items` and what have you tried so far for rendering the table ?

Comment: I will add new description

Comment: Hi Shyam, I already update my content. please see on it. thank you

Comment: Okay so what is the issue now ? your table is not rendering ? Also are you using any component library for your Table like material-ui ?

Comment: How to validate if the useSelector is null? because right now render of data in table happens if there is not null the useSelector

Comment: my map function shows like error of TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: there are many missing pieces in your code ? How you are forming the DataSource ?